# Subversion and AuthzSVNGroupsFile

Tags: svn

I want to split the majority of groups to be 'global' between repositories using the AuthzSVNGroupsFile  directive to point to a common location and I also want local authz with the relative URL syntax e..g. ^/authz.
This file would be synced to the LDAP groups.

However I would also like to be able to define groups in the local repository access file e.g. the group that sets access to the authz file or potentially others. As far as I can see you can only have one [groups] section in an authz file chain whether in one or two files - if you have multiple, only the last one is read.

So the more concise question - is it possible to define groups in both the

AuthzSVNGroupsFile

and

AuthzSVNAccessFile

if defined separately in the DAV setup?

Answer (score 0):

We have done in our system:

```
enable 

#LoadModule dav_svn_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
#LoadModule authz_svn_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so

Referral off
```

If you still have more questions, please post to answer.

Comment: I think the difficult bit is setting up the groups and access configuration, split between local and LDAP users in the same Apache instance, not just loading the modules.

Comment: I am not sure that this is possible - I have tried (and broken) auth changes by putting groups in the per-repo auth file and permissions in the group file (which are just ignored). Yesterday I just wrote a simple script to allow me to bulk edit the per-repo auth files - not ideal, but keeps me going.

Answer (score 0):

We just only add it on httpd.conf file for LDAP groups.

```
<Location /prj>
DAV svn
SVNPath /repos/prj/
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
#AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
AuthName "PRJ" repository"
AuthLDAPBindDN "SVNUsr@PRJ.NET"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "password"
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://try.prj.net:389/DC=prj,DC=net?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)" NONE
Require ldap-attribute objectClass=*
Require ldap-group CN=SVNPRJ,OU=SVN,OU=DEV,DC=PRJ,DC=NET
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Excellent right answer for the LDAP groups. We use the non LDAP for:

```
<Location /prj>
DAV svn
SVNListParentPath On
SVNPath /repos/prj/
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Subversion PRJ repository"
AuthUserFile /d00000/.auth/prj/prj-auth-file
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

You can view the challenges in following file to correct.
**Error log** 
var/log/apache2/error.log

Whenever finishing edit, the server
**bounce** 
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Hope that will help you to solve the challenges